# How to implement highly accurate timers in Linux Userspace?

Tags: linux, timer, beagleboard

I have Angstrom Linux on my BeagleBoard.

I want to implement very accurate timer which can fire at every 500us. I read about `hrtimers`, but all the implementations I found were for kernel space. I want to implement it in user space.

Is there any API which which can call into these `hrtimers`, which I can use in userspace or any other way of implementing accurate timer in linux?

I have set the `jiffy` to a few nanoseconds.

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) first, then consider [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` and/or [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and/or [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html); it might fit your needs. However, accuracy is hardware dependent!  I'm not sure you can get a 2000Hz periodic timer.

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch: I tried a similar code and it worked with average accuarcy. I have posted the details in my answer.

Comment: I have added the modified code.

Comment: Why exactly are you asking? Why do you need a very *accurate* timer in userspace (and not in the kernel)? What for?

Comment: Does it mean clock_gettime is actually using the cpu timers (like hrtimer in kernel) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, after some more efforts I found a code which suggested to use `timer_create()`, `clock_gettime()` in conjunction with signal handling (handling SIGALRM), similar to what *Basile Starynkevitch* suggested in his comment.

I tried it on my 1 GHz Beaglebone with clock type `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` for the interval of 500us.

Out of `10000` times the timer expired, `2%` of the time, it was exactly 500us (I ignored the nanosecond difference). and `96.6%` of the time it was in the range of `500 +/- 10us`. And the rest of the time, average error was not more than +/- 50us.

[This is the link for the code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160911022409/http://open-nandra.com/2008/12/testing-posix-high-resolution-timers/)

I have posted slightly modified version of code here. I did following modifications to the code:

1. For small intervals ~10us the `count` was getting infinitely decremented, therefore I added the control on number of tests (`count`) inside the signal handler itself.
2. Adding a `printf` in the middle of running timer costs a lot of time. Hence I stored the time difference in an array and then at the end i.e. after last test, I printed everything.
3. I thought calculating time difference in `unsigned long` (i.e. in nanoseconds) is better than calculating in `double` (in seconds) as it is more accurate and may be fast. Hence I modified the `timerdiff` macro to output difference in nanoseconds. Since I am using interval of 500us or less the difference will never overflow the range of `unsigned long`.

As you can see even after the modifications, only 2% of the results were accurate to <1us. Therefore now I am trying some more modifications like not running unnecessary linux processes, simplifying my program more, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000L

#define MAX_TESTS    10000

#define timerdiff(a,b) (((a)->tv_sec - (b)->tv_sec) * NSEC_PER_SEC + \
(((a)->tv_nsec - (b)->tv_nsec)))

static struct timespec prev = {.tv_sec=0,.tv_nsec=0};
static int count = MAX_TESTS;
unsigned long diff_times[MAX_TESTS];

void handler( int signo )
{
    struct timespec now;
    register int i, correct=0;

    if(count >= 0)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
        diff_times[count]=timerdiff(&now, &prev);
        prev = now;
        count --;
    }

    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<MAX_TESTS; ++i)
        {
            if(diff_times[i]/1000 < 510 && diff_times[i]/1000 > 490)
            {
                printf("%d->\t", i);
                correct++;
            }
            printf("%lu\n", diff_times[i]);
        }
        printf("-> %d\n", correct);
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    timer_t t_id;

    struct itimerspec tim_spec = {.it_interval= {.tv_sec=0,.tv_nsec=500000},
                    .it_value = {.tv_sec=1,.tv_nsec=0}};

    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t set;

    sigemptyset( &set );
    sigaddset( &set, SIGALRM );

    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_mask = set;
    act.sa_handler = &handler;

    sigaction( SIGALRM, &act, NULL );

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, &t_id))
        perror("timer_create");

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &prev);

    if (timer_settime(t_id, 0, &tim_spec, NULL))
        perror("timer_settime");

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a kernel with the "real-time" kernel preemption patches?  If you can, you should.  The choppiness you are seeing is likely due to non-preemptable stuff happening in the kernel right when the timer interrupt should fire; with kernel preemption the timer should be able to fire closer to perfectly on time.

Comment: Do you know how much overhead your solution has? Is there noticeable CPU overhead to generate and handle a signal that fires every 500us?

Comment: @Don't You Worry Child, How did you measure the timers accuracy ? using scope or some other method ? Thx

Comment: Did you ever try the realtime preemption patches and compare results?